# XMLHttpRequest randomly returning Error 500, can't figure out a pattern

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest, internal-server-error

I building a website, which must get data both from a MySQL database on the same server, and from an external API.

I have a javascript function which calls 5 other functions, and each of them creates an XMLHttpRequest to get different kinds of data:

```
function getData(){

    getGi(); //Function which calls an external API (Curl request) via a local php file

    getPQ(); //Gets data from a MySQL DB, also via a local php file, same as next 3 functions:
    getBS();
    getCV();
    getTP();
}
```

All 5 functions call a php file via XMLHttpRequest. The first php file's call is a simple curl request to an external API. The other 4 access a DB on the same server. Example (they are all similar):

```
function getCV(){

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "../php/getDB.php?t=CV", true);

    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            dados = JSON.parse(this.responseText.slice(0, -1));
            initCV(dados);
        }
    }
}
```

However, upon loading the website, a few Error 500 are thrown:

```
CV.js:14 GET https://<url>/php/getDB.php?t=CV 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

The number of errors or which of the requests throw errors seem random. Sometimes I get just one error, sometimes 3 or 4, and they are never the same files. Right now I've *"solved"* the issue by forcing the request to try again if it fails the first time:

```
xmlhttp.addEventListener("load", function() {
    if (xmlhttp.status == 500) {
        getCV();
        return
    }
});
```

But obviously this is not a proper solution. Any ideas on how I can debug/fix this? Or is this a server issue and I should contact my webhost?

Edit: here's the php code:

```
<?php
    //Settings
    $dbhost ="localhost";
    $dbuser = "user";
    $dbpass = "hunter2";
    $dbname ="database";

    //Read parameter
    $tipo = $_GET['t'];
    if (is_null($tipo)) {
        exit("Sem parâmetro.");
    }

    //connect to database
    $conn = @mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname) or die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());

    //query options
    mysqli_query($conn,"SET character_set_results = 'utf8mb4', character_set_client = 'utf8mb4', character_set_connection = 'utf8mb4', character_set_database = 'utf8mb4', character_set_server = 'utf8mb4'");

    switch($tipo) {
        case "CV":
            $query = "SELECT * FROM table1";
        break;

        case "PI":
            $query = "SELECT * FROM table2";
        break;

        case "PQ":
            $query = "SELECT * FROM table3";
        break;

        case "TP":
            $query = "SELECT * FROM table4";
        break;

        case "BS":
            $query = "SELECT * FROM table5";
        break;

        default:
            exit("Parametro invalido.");
    }

    //Execute query
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if (!$result){
        echo "Couldn't execute the query";
        die();
    }

    else{
        $data = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $data[]=$row;
        }
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);

    echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

Comment: I'd start finding out what kind of the server error is encountered by investigating the web server's log files.

Comment: Without seeing the PHP code it's hard to say. Given four of the five are database requests you could be running into timing issues on database operations.

Comment: but also with that patch all the requests fail right?

Comment: @Nick I just posted the php code.

Comment: There's nothing obvious in the PHP code. As @marekful said, you should check the server's PHP and MySQL log files for errors.